# Using PublishTransactionState filter in GetSystemWideList does not work

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I tried to apply a filter for the PublishTransactionState when using the GetSystemWideList operation on the Core Service (SDL Tridion 2011 SP1).

If I try set filter values like PublishTransactionState.ScheduledForPublish or PublishTransactionState.WaitingForPublish I get no results, even though I know for sure there are publish transactions with this status in the queue.

```
var filter = new PublishTransactionsFilterData {ForRepository = new LinkToRepositoryData {IdRef = "tcm:0-69-1"}};
filter.PublicationTarget = new LinkToPublicationTargetData { IdRef = "tcm:0-1-65537" };
filter.PublishTransactionState = PublishTransactionState.ScheduledForPublish;
//filter.StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

var transactions = coreServiceSession.GetSystemWideList(filter);
Console.WriteLine(transactions.Count() + " publish transactions");
```

With the filter.PublishTransactionState line enabled, the core service always returns 0 results. With this line commented we will get the list of publish transactions as expected, this includes some transactions with state SceduledForPublish.

Other filters, like the StartDate filter work as expected.

Anyone has this working?

Comment: I can easily reproduce your problem: there are clearly results with `State = ScheduleForPublish`, but adding that condition to the filter returns no results.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Thanks for your confirmation.

To my surprise I just notices filtering on PublishTransactionState.Success does work correctly.

Also, I get the same behavior when applying these filters in the Publishing Queue in the CME.

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue which has been fixed in 2013.

There is no hotfix available right now, but you can work around it by requesting the list without setting the PublishTransactionState property and then post-processing the result.

Comment: Be sure to set a date range into the future in that case, otherwise you'll end up retrieving way more transactions than necessary.

Comment: Yes, the code example already showed the StartDate, set to one day back, just in case the publisher is a little busy. 
   //filter.StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
It will have quite a bit of a performance when the system processes a lot of publishing transactions though. You might end up wading trough 100rds of publish transactions to filter a couple of scheduled ones.

Comment: Found some more info in the CM database. The STATE column in the PUBLISH_TRANSACTIONS table has the value 0 instead of 1 (Scheduled for publishing). Probably a bug, cause state 0 does not exist. Overview of publishing states: sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/

Comment: @Frank if you set it in the future, you wouldn't find anything at all -- since the Start/End date properties on the filter are about the time the transaction was created or modified (not about when the item will be published). At least according to the documentation.